# Ayuda con: NoReverseMatch at!

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

ayuda con este error:

> ```
> Reverse for 'pedido_sub' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments 
> '{'cod_experto': 'AA-0002', 'id_pedido': 53}' not found. 
> 1 pattern(s) tried: 
> ['solicitar/aprobar/(?P<id_pedido>\\d+)/(?P<cod_experto>\\d+)$']
> ```

- Me marca en rojo el tag del index.html:

```python
< a href="{% url "usuario:pedido_sub" id_pedido=ped.id cod_experto=ped.articulo.cod_experto %}" 
    type="submit"
```

- El código de este botón se encuentra en views.py:

```python
def pedido_sub(request, id_pedido, cod_experto):
    art = Articulo.objects.get(id=cod_experto)
    pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_pedido)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pedido.estado = 'entregado'
        pedido.save()
        pedido.fecha_entrega = datetime.now()
        pedido.save()
        art.stock = pedido.cantidad - art.stock
        art.save()
        return redirect('usuario:home')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'pedido':pedido}, {'art':art})
```

Lo que hace el def, es extraer el id del pedido y tambien el del artículo (`cod_experto`), botón que modifica dos campos, esto lo hace sin problemas, pero al incorporar la resta del campo cantidad de tabla Pedido y stock de tabla Articulo, ocurre este error y no he podido corregirlo, si pueden ayudarme y aconsejarme lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un NoReverseMatch tiene que ver con resolución de urls, lo que te esta indicando es que la url que intentas resolver cuando haces

`< a href="{% url "usuario:pedido_sub" id_pedido=ped.id cod_experto=ped.articulo.cod_experto %}" 
    type="submit"`

No coincide con ninguna de las definidas, si te fijas a detalle la definición de la misma url que te muestra el error

`['solicitar/aprobar/(?P<id_pedido>\\d+)/(?P<cod_experto>\\d+)$']` te indica que la variable cod_experto la has definido como un digito (d+ significa que esta esperando uno o mas digitos) por ende al pasar el codigo `'AA-0002'` no hace match ya que esta recibiedo caracteres

Te recomendaría que redefinieras tu url de la siguiente forma

`['solicitar/aprobar/(?P<id_pedido>\\d+)/(?P<cod_experto>\\w+)$']`

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el error esta en la misma resta, en:

```
art.stock = pedido.cantidad - art.stock
```

- Seguramente el error se ocasiona en porque la base de datos tiene una condición para no aceptar valores menores a 0.
  Si a= 2 y b= 5, a - b = -3, imagino que en el stock no debe haber menos de 0 artículos por tanto te lanza el error.
- posible solución:

`art.stock -= pedido.cantidad`

- o igualmente

`art.stock = art.stock - pedido.cantidad`

También me pregunto por que guardas el pedido antes y después de de fecha de entrega?

```
pedido.save()
pedido.fecha_entrega = datetime.now()
pedido.save()
```

Comment: bueno, si e cambiado la resta y el guardado al final, de pedido, pero el mismo error persiste, no encuentro solución para esto :/

Comment: @Demaro el error dice que no se encuentra, solo se me ocurren una teoría, en `pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_pedido)` estas intentando obtener un pedido que no esta registrado en la base de datos. Ciertamente no sabría que decirte sin mayor información de tu parte. revisa los módulos involucrados y la base de datos y danos un poco de estructura para poder ayudarte. Edita tu pregunta con nueva información, cambios que realizaste.